# Is it possible to run local servers on AWS-CodeBuild?

Tags: aws-codebuild

Good Morning,

I'm using CodeBuild to test my application,

I was wondering if its possible to run a local Server inside a build.

I create a NPM script to start a local server, but every time I ran de tests, the CodeBuild pass through the command without waiting.

I searched on AWS Documentation and they say to use "nohup" command, but It doesn't work for me.

Just to be clear, my expectations is that CodeBuild ran the command, wait to be finished and proceed to another command without closing the open server.

Any of you guys have an idea?

Command:

```
- nohup yarn start-server
```

Answer (score 0):

Start a background process and wait for it to complete later:

```
nohup sleep 30 & echo $! > pidfile
…
wait $(cat pidfile)
```

Start a background process and do not wait for it to ever complete:

```
nohup sleep 30 & disown $!
```

Start a background process and kill it later:

```
nohup sleep 30 & echo $! > pidfile
…
kill $(cat pidfile)
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-background-tasks.html